# You have a WCF service/resource. when you get a message/request your codes needs to send another message to another service

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a scenario where a client requests my service then my service(A) requests another service(B), service(B) returns a value that service(A) uses it to return a value to the client.
I am using multi threading to capture the whole scenario.
I have looked at Rerant multi threading but cannot work as i have multiple clients that will be accessing the same service.
could someone please point to me the direction. Kind regards.

Comment: Can't you just use [ConcurrencyMode.Multiple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx)?

Comment: If you don't mind, why you have such scenario at the first hand? It seems to me it will cause you a lot of headaches even though it will work. Why not client can directly call service B without passing through service A?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your services to [ConcurrencyMode.Multiple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) and [InstanceContextMode.Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontext.aspx), and then handle multithreading manually in each of the single server instances.

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
public class BService : IB
{ ... }
```

MSDN has an [article on Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx) describing the consequences of using this model, as well as other options.

If you're using .NET 4.5, you can avoid locking up a thread in service A while waiting for the response from service B by using the Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern as described in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx).